# Why this Laravel code returns an empty array?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I have three items on database and `Permissions` table, but this code returns an empty array. I get no errors on page. There's only empty drop-down menu. (I'm using Laravel 5.4)

#### model: Permission.php

```
protected $fillable = ['name' , 'label'];

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

#### controller: (Problem occurs in this page\controller)

```
public function create()
{
    return view('Admin.roles.create');
}
```

#### view (problematic part):

```
@foreach(\App\Permission::latest()->get() as $permission)
      <option value="{{ $permission->id }}">{{$permission->name }} - {{$permission->label }}</option>
     @endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show us the code within Permission::latest()?

Comment: In `php artisan tinker`, check that `App\Permission::latest()->get()` actually fetches any results.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes it returns true results. so its View layer problem? (not back-end?)

Comment: Is this `@foreach` wrapped in a `<select>` element as you'd expect?

Comment: Show the results of `App\Permission::latest()->get()`